# Jsoup - get url from element

Tags: web-crawler, jsoup

I have an element link.(link is `<li class="books"><a href="catagory.php?cat=books">Books</a></li>`)

I am trying to parse the hred from this element using 
`String url = link.attr("href");` It gives an empty string. Why?

(abs:href is also tried. Not working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should drill down to a specific element and then use the selector.

```
link.select("li a").attr("href")
```

In this case we need the `attr` of `"a"` element and not the `"li"`